# Is it possible specify to gradle to wait until a CompletableFuture is completed?

Tags: java, gradle, testing, completable-future

I have to test a method that returns a `CompletableFuture`. To run the tests I launch the command: `gradlew test`. Here an example of the implementation:

```java
// Method
public CompletableFuture<String> foo() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      // Computation took about 3 sec ...

      return "ABC";
    });
  }
}

// Test
@Test
void test() {
  foo().whenComplete((s, throwable) -> {
    System.out.println(s);
  });
}
```

The callback inside `.whenComplete` is never runs because the main thread exit before the complete computation of the `foo` method.

I tried to use the `join()` method above the `whenComplete()` method, but it's stopped the main thread.

Is it possible, keep running tests in parallel and wait that all the callbacks are completed before killing the main thread?

Comment: Probably not outside of storing the CF in some kind of var and putting a `finalizedBy` task on the outermost boundary that checks `while(!fooVar.isDone());`...  You created the thread yourself, which means you need to keep Gradle "busy" until it finishes.